# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match') works while logging but not while assigning to a const

Tags: node.js, match, typeerror

In my backend code written in node, `const result = formulaString.match(y)` this particular line gives me an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')`. It's frustrating because `console.log(formulaString.match(y))` this works exactly as intended.

My node version is `v16.13.1` if that's relevant.

Comment: the error is formulaString is not defined.
Could you shared the entire function?

Comment: it really depends (1) on your code and (2) on the values of `formulaString` and `y`. could you paste your code as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?